# Forcing a foreign key column name via DataAnnotation not working

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, data-annotations, entity-framework-5

Ok I've got two classes: 'Plan' and 'Material'. A plan has 0..1 material and a material can be contained in multiple plans. When my database is created the auto-generated column is named `Material_MaterialId` and I want it to be named `MaterialId`

My 'Plan' class:

```
[Column("MaterialId")]
public virtual Material Material { get; set; }
```

My 'Material' class:

```
public int MaterialId { get; set; }
```

But it doesn't seems to be doing anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use this:

Plan Class

```
public virtual Material Material { get; set; }

public int? MaterialId { get; set; } /* it prompt clr create foreign key MatherialId which referenced to MatherialId class of Matherial */
```

Matherial class

```
public int MaterialId { get; set; }
```

**UPDATED**

**Full solution**

Entities:

```
namespace MvcApplicationTest.Models
{
    public class Material
    {
        public int MaterialId { get; set; }
        public int Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Plan
    {
        public int PlanId { get; set; }
        public int Name { get; set; }

        //full navigation property
        public virtual Material Material { get; set; }
        public int? MaterialId { get; set; } 
        //

    }

    public class TestContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Material> Materials { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Plan> Plans { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Some initialization in global.asax :

```
var context = new TestContext();
context.Database.CreateIfNotExists();
```

And result should be like this:

[image]

For your names:

```
 [ForeignKey("MaterialFK")]
 public virtual Material MyMaterial { get; set; } //your name
 public int? MaterialFK { get; set; } //your name
```

Comment: In my view I can't use MaterialId to access the other propreties which is normal because it's an int (`@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.MaterialId.Name)` doesn't work), but `@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.Material.Name)` works... it's a bit weird

Comment: Why it is weird? MaterialId - is a foreigh key in db, but Material - it is a navigation property in EF class, and using navigation property you can get name of Matherial.

Comment: Got it, seems weird to me anyway, not really used to it. But I am forced to give my FK the name of the PK from my other class, what if I want another name?

Comment: For another name you can use System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, try to use this:   
        [ForeignKey("MaterialFK")]
        public virtual Material MyMaterial { get; set; } //your name
        public int? MaterialFK { get; set; } //your name
        //

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this will do the trick:

```
[Column(Name="MaterialId")]
public virtual Material Material { get; set; }
```

Otherwise, you may be able to do it by overriding the `OnModelCreating` method of your DbContext with something similar to this:

```
public class YourContext: DbContext
{
  public DbSet<Plan> Plans { get; set; }
  public DbSet<Material> Materials { get; set; }

  public YourContext()
    : base("YourDb")
  {
  }

  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
    modelBuilder.Entity<Plan>().
      HasMany(c => c.Material).
      Map(
       m =>
       {
         m.MapLeftKey("MaterialId");
         m.MapRightKey("PlanId");
         m.ToTable("Plans");
       });
  }
}
```